# How does Web Assembly facilitate less hackable/more trustless in-browser code execution?

Tags: webassembly

i.e. for one, precompiled code is harder to read therefore making it more difficult to meaningfully alter browser code.

How is it more 'sandboxed' than JS, and does this make it less hackable?

"WebAssembly is specified to be run in a safe, sandboxed execution environment." - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAssembly/Concepts

Are there properties of the WASM VM memory format that make it more client-side-hack-resistant?

Anything else?

Comment: Being harder to read does not make it less hackable in any way...

Comment: All else being equal: Code that's harder to read = code that's more difficult to hack '...'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

WebAssembly was never designed to be less hackable than JavaScript. WebAssembly modules run within the browser and can be inspected and debugged just like any other JavaScript application. The only additional protection they offer is that of obfuscation. It is a lower level language which makes it harder to decipher the code - although that is not a strong protection!

WebAssembly modules are sandboxed in that one module cannot access the memory, or interact with, another running module. They have their own isolated execution environment. JavaScript is also sandboxed in order to prevent code from one tab or page interacting with another - and more importantly preventing it from accessing the underlying host OS!

Webassembly uses linear memory, which is a contiguous block of memory, that is typical used to create a heap. It can be exported to the host environment, which means that the hosting JavaScript code can directly read and write to it as a byte array.

In summary, WebAssembly is not less hackable and has a different sandbox. If these are the trains you’re looking at this technology, perhaps it’s time for a rethink?

Comment: Great distilled insight.

WASM = lower level therefor more obfuscated + module sandboxing (unless exported). JS = window/page sandboxing.


">which means that the hosting JavaScript code can directly read and write to it as a byte array."

By this, do you meant the JS code which complies/instantiates & runs a WASM module? i.e. WebAssembly.compileStreaming()/WebAssembly.instantiateStreaming()

Comment: Thanks :-) when a wasm module is instantiatied the functions, global variables and memory it imports / exports is defined. If linear memory is exported, any JavaScript code that has a reference to the module will be able to read and write to module memory. Typically this is the code that instantiates the module.

Comment: @AskP, ColinE, sorry, but this answer is incorrect. Wasm was most definitely designed for sandboxing, while JS never was. Specifically, Wasm modules provide perfect encapsulation: a module has *no ambient capabilities*, only its imports; the client has no access to a module's innards, only its exports. That's not even remotely true of JavaScript.

Comment: @AndreasRossberg Isn't what your comment describes just a kind of default module runtime encapsulation that ColinE described in his answer? (which seals off just one class of client vulnerability). Webassembly can still be altered/hacked (i.e. via debugger breakpoints) just like any other client JS, no?

Comment: @AskP, no, a JS program, by default, has access to the entire JS and DOM library, so can do everything. A Wasm module has no access to anything unless you explicitly provide it.

Comment: @AndreasRossberg Are you saying that a hacker can't set a breakpoint in client JS code before wasm module instantiation, change the wasm module code to import & use whichever runtime environment objects (DOM, library etc.) desired, and then supply the module those env. objects for use?

Comment: @AskP, somebody taking control of the page obviously can do anything, but they cannot *get* such control through Wasm code, only through JS code.

Comment: "but they cannot get such control through Wasm code, only through JS code." - well put. By "the client has no access to a module's innards, only its exports.", you mean no code outside a wasm module has programmatic access to the module's innards, only to what that module exports, right?

Answer (score 6):

On the web, WebAssembly runs in the same sandbox as JavaScript, so WebAssembly cannot affect its host machine in any way that could not also be done with pure JavaScript. But WebAssembly goes further and *does* make it safer to run untrusted code because of how its imports work.

When a WebAssembly module is instantiated, it is supplied with a set of imported functions. These imports are the only host functions that the module has access to, and they cannot be changed once the module has been instantiated. Without imports, a WebAssembly module can only express pure computation and can only affect the state of its own memory. That means that if you don't supply any imports that can make network requests, you can be certain that the WebAssembly module cannot make network requests. Contrast this to JavaScript, where figuring out whether a program uses a particular API is undecidable in general.

That does not mean that the code in the WebAssembly module cannot have bugs or security vulnerabilities. For example, buffer overrun attacks on buggy C programs are still possible when those C programs are compiled to WebAssembly, but the difference is that the worst they can do is determined by the imports, which are easy to inspect. So if you import `eval` into your buggy C WebAssembly module you might have serious problems, but if you only import `console.log`, the worst an attacker could do is spam your console.

I don't view WebAssembly being low level as relevant to security. WebAssembly modules are no harder to read than minimized or obfuscated JavaScript, and the difference all but disappears when you consider asm.js-style JavaScript. Certainly it is harder to read a WebAssembly module than a pretty-printed JavaScript program, but that doesn't really get you anywhere in terms of security.

Comment: Quick addition: The WebAssembly VM is a Von Neumann architecture. So while your C program might still have buffer overflows, they can’t be exploited (as easily). A program can’t execute code from memory nor can it change its own code.

Comment: @Surma, I suppose you meant to say that Wasm is **not** a von Neumann architecture?

Comment: Eugh yes, NOT Von Neumann, it IS a Harvard architecture. Thanks for catching that.